# can't call a function and pass a var using mvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, umbraco7

I am new to MVC, I looked at other solutions to my problem on web but still I can't find what is wrong with my code, I'm using code (as is) from umbraco website, I'm trying to call a function and pass a var from js, I don't understand what is the problem..., tried to solve it with online examples but getting the same error... help

//c#

```
  public class MokedLoginController : SurfaceController
    {                
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("umbraco/surface/MokedLogin/DoLogin/{id}")]
        public void DoLogin([FromBody]int member)
        {
            var _member = Services.MemberService.GetById(member);

            if (_member != null)
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(_member.Username, false);
        }
    }
```

//js

```
angular.module('umbraco').controller('MokedLoginController', [

    '$scope',
    '$http',
    'editorState',
    'contentResource',

    function ($scope, $http, editorState, contentResource) {

        // Check if you are creating a new member
        $scope.isNew = editorState.current.id <= 0;

        // Define the login as member function
        $scope.loginAsMember = function () {

            // ### Setup cookie  ????           
            var url = '/umbraco/surface/MokedLogin/DoLogin/{id}';                            
            // Get the current member id using the editorState
            var _memberId = editorState.current.id;
    // Do Login
        $http.post(
            url, _memberId
           ).then(
            function (response) {                       
                    // ### Redirect  ????
                    // Get the redirect page from config
                    var urlPageRedirect = $scope.model.config.memberRedirectPage;

                    // Check if page is set in the config
                    if (urlPageRedirect)
                    {
                        contentResource.getNiceUrl(urlPageRedirect).then(function (data) {
                            window.open(data, '_blank') // Get the first url
                        });
                    } else {
                        // Open the root page
                        window.open('/', '_blank');
                    }
                },
                function (error) {
                console.log(error.data);
                }
            );
        };
    }
]);
            // Do Login
            $http.post(
```

**// the famouse exception that comes from ? and why ?** 
System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'member' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'Void DoLogin(Int32)'
 in 'ThePoolInsurance.Web.Controllers.MokedLoginController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

Comment: what is this [FromBody] in the controller?

Comment: The error message is saying that your parameter needs to be either a reference type, nullable type, or declared as an optional parameter. `int` is a non-nullable value type, so if you want it your parameter to be an `int`, you need to change the signature to be `public void DoLogin([FromBody]int member = 0)` (or whatever other default value) in order for it to be accepted.

Comment: @Abion47 thank you! it finds the function but the param is 0 and not the one I passed..